# Spring Boot Startup stuck at - INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am not able to start my spring boot application from eclipse or even command prompt as the application startup gets stuck at the following:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2018-08-19 16:36:42,769 restartedMain ERROR Console contains an invalid element or attribute ""

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

Aug 19, 2018 4:36:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Aug 19, 2018 4:36:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
Aug 19, 2018 4:36:47 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 19, 2018 4:36:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-19 16:36:48.213  INFO 9288 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper                      : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-08-19 16:36:48.301  INFO 9288 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.Version                              : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2018-08-19 16:36:48.303  INFO 9288 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.Environment                        : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-08-19 16:36:48.305  INFO 9288 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.Environment                        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-08-19 16:36:48.361  INFO 9288 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.a.c.Version                          : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-08-19 16:36:48.665  INFO 9288 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.d.Dialect                            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Aug 19, 2018 4:36:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
Aug 19, 2018 4:36:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
Aug 19, 2018 4:36:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
```

I did not make any changes in my application and all of a sudden i am not able to start my application. What can be the issue?

Comment: It seems to be issue with multie tomcat libs .

Answer (score 0):

It appers to be issue with multiple tomcat libs.
Check if tomcat 7.x is getting transitively added by some dependencies. Exclude it and build run again